# Deploying NLog with a ClickOnce application

Tags: .net, clickonce, nlog

Users are not able to install a ClickOnce application. The error is: "File NLog.dll is not a valid Portable Executable (PE) file." It works fine on my machine, but I have nLog installed. That's not possible for client machines. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer to this issue when your `NLog.config` would not be copied to your program if installed using `ClickOnce`.

You need to select the `NLog.config` file in your `Project` using `Solution Explorer` and set its `Properties` as follows:

- **Build Action**: Content
- **Copy to Output Directory**: Copy always

Now when you deploy using `ClickOnce` the files should be copied over as well! :)

Answer (score 7):

I put all the NLog config data into the App.config file instead of the NLog.config file and it worked for me after deploying with ClickOnce as well. No errors and the logging was working on the deployed application.

Answer (score 3):

Check your build option and make sure NLog.dll is included in the "Application Files", so that it will be in "download group"/required.

Comment: This is most likely the problem since NLog should just be another dll that you can include.  Log4Net works this way.

Comment: Thanks but the dll does get downloaded, it just gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

If your NLog assemblies are deployed to the GAC then you can't (simply) include that in a ClickOnce setup. Try to deploy them as local DLLs.  If that is not possible you will need a separate Setup (or MSI) to deploy NLog.

Comment: To further Henk's answer, the nlog install should have included a non-GACed dll somewhere that you can use, or you should be able to download one from their site (often in a zip file rather than installer).

Comment: We use NLog here as well without (too much) problems but our dll's are deployed locally with the application.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dll to your project and set BuildAction = None, and "copy to output directory" as "do not copy".

Delete your reference to NLog in your project. Re-add the reference and point it to the dll you just added to the project. On the properties of the reference, set "Copy local" to "true".

Now when YOU run the application, it will point to the local version, and when you deploy the application, it will deploy the local version and point to it.

This works for many 3rd party DLL's, but not all. The best thing to do is to try it.

Comment: Thanks but the dll does get downloaded, it just gives an error.

Comment: How is it referenced in your project? I'm going to have to dredge my memory, I remember something about the portable execution error... You did change your project to reference it the way I've said here?

Comment: Here's a post from the MSDN forum -- see if this helps you at all: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/dc47dac1-6eb2-4533-a119-c1d87a36c4a5/